# Rails loop through data in a form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, for-loop

I would like to loop through data in my database inside my form. What I would like to do with the data is put it in labels and textboxes. How could I do this in rails? Would I just use a .each block to loop through it inside the form? The reason I have it in my database is because my client would like to be able to add the form field data himself.

---

For example here is something I would like to do:

```
<%= form_for :order do |f| %>
  @fields.each do |field|
    <%= f.label field.name %>
    <%= f.text_field field.name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

What the best way to accomplish something like this?

Please don't answer with a railscast :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Railscast is a helpful resource which you can learn "how to catch fish". If you just ask questions on SO and someone "get you fish", you are not really learning anything, but just temporarily solving a problem. In return, this method will consume more amount of time than just learning the rails with railscasts or with books.

Comment: @Jake - it's generally considered good form to "accept' an answer if it solves your problem. You can do that by clicking the "tick" on the left of the answer. :)

Comment: +1 on not responding with a RailsCast.  They are a good resource, but they should only be used as adding additional resources to the end of an answer, not the answer itself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that will work, though you missed an end script tag on line two:

```
<%= form_for :order do |f| %>
   <% @fields.each do |field| %>  
       <%= f.label field.name %>
       <%= f.text_field field.name %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If you need something more complex than just a label/text field pair - then you can use a partial-template and use the collection keyword:

```
<!-- in 'order.html.erb' -->
<%= form_for :order do |f| %>
   <!-- note: each 'field' is auto-populated from the collection/partial-name, but you need to pass the form in as a local -->
   <%= render :partial => 'field', :collection => @fields, :locals => {:f => f} %>  
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<!-- in '_field.html.erb' -->
<%= f.label field.name %>
<%= f.text_field field.name %>
<!-- and whatever else you want to do... -->
```

more on partial rendering here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html

Comment: instead of using a locals could I use an object?