# Rail 5: Saving fields from loop in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have an app where users can request participation on events. When admins create Events, they add Spaces that will be available to apply for (like "tables", "racks" etc and their price).

When the user initialize the request wizard, a Request is automatically created, and a RequestSpace are automatically created for the request, one for each of the Event.spaces, with the default value of 0. The user can request the amount they want of each space type by increasing the number in the form.

It's kind of like a shopping cart where user change quantity of a product in a number field, except that here the products (spaces) are predefined by Event.

This means that the Request form gets a number field for each associated RequestSpace. I have this form rendering in the view, and it looks the way I want. The problem is that I don't know how to save each row in the update action in the requests controller.

The relevant code from the models:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :requests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :spaces, dependent: :destroy
...

class Space < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :request_spaces
...

class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :request_spaces
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :request_spaces
...

class RequestSpace < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :space
...
```

The form:

```
<%= form_for(@request, local: true) do |form| %>
  ...
  <% @request.request_spaces.each do |rs| %>
    <%= form.fields_for :request_spaces, rs do |s| %>
      <%= s.number_field :amount, min: "0", max: "#{rs.space.max_amount}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

the strong parameters in requests_controller.rb:

```
params.require(:request).permit(<other params omitted>, reqeust_spaces_attributes:[:id, :amount])
```

When I save the changes in the form, the RequestSpaces :amount field is not updated. Any idea on how to solve this in the controller?

EDIT:

This SO question/answer described a similar problem, and inspired the loop solution for the form fields: [Rails loop through data in a form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551617/rails-loop-through-data-in-a-form-field)

Comment: why you are using loop ? There is no need to use loop in nested form .

Comment: because there are more than one row in RequestSpaces for each request, pre-created based on Spacec associated with the Event. It's all described in the question. :-)

Comment: As per your code you create form of request space for one already created request space . is it ? do you want that  ? If you already have pre define request spaces. why you are using it in creating another new request spaces for request ?

Comment: they're not being created when saving the form, both request and request_spaces are supposed to be updated on submission. They are all created automatically when the user initializa a wizard.

Comment: Remove loop and add this instead of loop `<%= form.fields_for :request_spaces do |rd| %>` . let me know if it not work

Comment: I tried to remove loop, and It made no difference, actually. The number fields for each  RequestSpace auto-created based on Event-spaces are displayed as they should, but changes are still not changed in the database. Do I have to add something in the update action in requests controller to handle the params for the nested resourdce RequestSpace in addition to the strong params?

Comment: i dont understand . whats the issue ! but you should read this article . it will help you https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Comment: Thank you! The issue remains that the request's request_spaces are dynamically created based on Event.spaces, and not fixed fields like the  User.address example from the article. And I don't know how to handle the changes in the controller (if that's were the problem is)

Comment: there is no issue if you have dynamic values created or pre defined.

Comment: Updates are still not persisted in the DB. I updated my question with a reference to a similar SO question/answer.